# How do overridden method calls from base-class methods work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

According to the [docs on inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

> Derived classes may override methods of their base classes. Because methods have no special privileges when calling other methods of the same object, a method of a base class that calls another method defined in the same base class may end up calling a method of a derived class that overrides it.

How does that happen? Can someone illustrate this concept with a simple example?

Comment: From the help centre: "if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format". Try typing *python inheritance* in your nearest google kiosk. Read the first five links, then ask specific questions about specific things you don't understand.

Comment: I think this is a great question to ask. The author is asking a question not about inheritance in general, but about a very specific Python feature.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's the example you requested. This prints `chocolate`.

```
class Base:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")
    def bar(self):
        self.foo()

class Derived(Base):
    def foo(self):
        print("chocolate")

d = Derived()
d.bar()  # prints "chocolate"
```

The string `chocolate` is printed instead of `foo` because `Derived` overrides the `foo()` function. Even though `bar()` is defined in `Base`, it ends up calling the `Derived` implementation of `foo()` instead of the `Base` implementation.

Comment: Ah that's simple enough. To be 100% clear, the methods of an **instance** of `Base` could never execute methods of `Derived`? which I had thought the docs were implying.

Comment: @innisfree: You're right, they can't. Imagine a setup where you have multiple derived classes from one base class. Which derived class would the base class look at to execute the method?

Comment: @innisfree `d` is also an instance of `Base`, that might be were the confusion stems from. But yes, `Base().bar()` won't call any overwritten methods

Comment: @innisfree Unless you monkey patch the instance, of course. E.g., `b = Base(); b.foo = Derived.foo.__get__(b); b.bar()`. But this would never happen without you explicitly putting in code for it.

Answer (score 17):

#### How does it work?

When an attribute look-up is performed on an instance of the class, the class dictionary **and** the dictionaries of its base classes are searched in a certain order (see: [**Method Resolution Order**](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)) for the appropriate method. What is found *first* is going to get called.

Using the following `Spam` example:

```
class Spam:
    def produce_spam(self):
        print("spam")
    def get_spam(self):
        self.produce_spam()

class SuperSpam(Spam):
    def produce_spam(self):
        print("super spam")
```

`Spam` defines the functions `produce_spam` and `get_spam`. These live in its `Spam.__dict__` (class namespace). The sub-class `SuperSpam`, by means of inheritance, has access to both these methods. `SuperSpam.produce_spam` doesn't replace `Spam.produce_spam`, it is simply found first when the look-up for the name `'produce_spam'` is made on one of its instances.

Essentially, the result of inheritance is that the dictionaries of any base classes are also going to get searched if, after an attribute look-up on the sub-class is made, the attribute isn't found in the sub-class's dictionary.

When the function `get_spam` is first invoked with:

```
s = SuperSpam()
s.get_spam()
```

the sequence of events *roughly* goes like this:

- Look into `SuperSpam`s `__dict__` for `get_spam`.
- Since it isn't found in `SuperSpam`s `__dict__` look into the dictionaries of it's base classes (`mro` chain).
- `Spam` is next in the `mro` chain, so `get_spam` is found in `Spam`'s dictionary.

Now, when `produce_spam` is looked up in the body of `get_spam` with `self.produce_spam`, the sequence is much shorter:

- Look into `SuperSpam`'s (`self`) `__dict__`  for `produce_spam`.
- Find it, get it and call it.

`produce_spam` is found in the `__dict__` first so that gets fetched.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Base():
    def m1(self):
        return self.m2()
    def m2(self):
        return 'base'

class Sub(Base):
    def m2(self):
        return 'sub'

b = Base()
s = Sub()
print(b.m1(), s.m1())
```

prints "base sub"

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate how it works consider these two classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    def eat(self):
        print("I don't want to eat that {}.".format(self.takefrompocket()))

    def takefrompocket(self):
        return 'apple'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Looking for:', name)
        method_to_use = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        print('Found method:', method_to_use)
        return method_to_use

class Child(Parent):
    def takefrompocket(self):
        return 'salad'
```

The `__getattribute__` method is responsible in new-style-classes (like all classes in python3) for the attribute lookup. It is just implemented to `print` what each lookup does - **normally you don't want to and shouldn't implement it yourself**. The lookup follows pythons [method resolution order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) just if you are really interested.

```
>>> some_kid = Child()
>>> some_kid.eat()
Looking for: eat
Found method: <bound method Parent.eat of <__main__.Child object at 0x0000027BCA4EEA58>>
Looking for: takefrompocket
Found method: <bound method Child.takefrompocket of <__main__.Child object at 0x0000027BCA4EEA58>>
I don't want to eat that salad.
```

So when you want to use `eat` then it uses `Parent.eat` in this example. But `self.takefrompocket` is used from `Child`.

```
>>> some_parent = Parent()
>>> some_parent.eat()
Looking for: eat
Found method: <bound method Parent.eat of <__main__.Parent object at 0x0000027BCA4EE358>>
Looking for: takefrompocket
Found method: <bound method Parent.takefrompocket of <__main__.Parent object at 0x0000027BCA4EE358>>
I don't want to eat that apple.
```

Here both methods are taken from `Parent`. Inherited classes don't (generally) interfere with their ancestors!

Answer (score -3):

If your child class doesn't implement the method, raise an exception!

```
class Base(object):

    def something (self):
        raise ('Not implemented')
```

Comment: Could you format your code and include the minimal example the OP wanted (i.e. with child class and execution)?

Comment: This in no way answers the question "how can it happen".