# How can a method object call a function inside another class

Tags: function, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Here is the requested construct, demands lie in the code snippet:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.func1()

    def func1(self):
        blah blah ... blah 


class class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.func2()

    def func2(self):
        call function func1 of class1
```

Comment: Make class2 a derived class of class1.

Comment: In order to do that, you need an instance of `class1` to use to call `func1()`.  You get that by passing an instance of `class1` to `class2`, or by creating one in `class2.__init__()` or `class2.func2()`.  There's no trick, but no magic either - if you want to call a member function of a class, you need an instance of that class.  If you need an instance, somebody needs to make it, and may need to pass it around.

Comment: than you for answering

Answer (score 0):

Make class2 a derived class of class1:

```
class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.func2()
    def func2(self):
        self.func1()
```

I have asked a similar question before, more detailed illustrations are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236190/how-do-overridden-method-calls-from-base-class-methods-work).